# Font size form native settings overlaps in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, fonts, constraints, size

I have an app with a ConstraintLayout in which I organize some textview and a piechart.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/crv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/mycolor1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="MY VALUES"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="MY VALUE 1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pic1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="MY VALUE 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txv5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pic1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv3" />

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                    android:id="@+id/pic1"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_pie_chart"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_pie_chart"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my result who works fine if font size from native settings is "normal":
[image]

But if I increase the font size from Android native settings from:
[image]

To:

[image]

My textviews overlaps...

[image]

There is a way to force my code to ignore native font size settings ?
Alternatively I can Constraint my textviews on the left by the end to the start of my textsize on the right and set ellipsize, like this:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txv2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:text="MY VALUE 1"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txv3"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txv3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pic1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />
```

Anyway If I do this, my textview on the left do not clip to the left of the parent, and the result isn't good. How can I force textviews to clip to the left of parent?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/txv2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:text="MY VALUE 1"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txv3"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />
```

with

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txv2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:text="MY VALUE 1"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txv3"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv1" />
```

The key is in this line:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

This will make your left view end with the constraint properly.